# How to rename the all the column name at one shot

Tags: pandas

My column names are `A_X,B_X,C_X`

How to rename to A, B, C

Not with rename(dictionary) any other way is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming names are consistent use `str.split` with `str` as:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_').str[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

If the names follow that convention then:

```
df.columns = [x[0] for x in df.columns]
```

Now it is possible to have multiple letters before the undescore, in that case I would use:

```
df.columns = [x.split('_')[0] for x in df.columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.columns = "A B C".split()
```

It's more convenient to write it with `.split()` than `["A", "B", "C"]`.